# Compare 2 Columns in 2 different files

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, scripting, merge

I need to subtract second and third columns between 2 files based on the first column and do not show rows with diff_column_2(DIFF-IO)=diff_column_3(DIFF-SELECT)=0. *Noting that the order can be random except the last row which exists in both files and should remain at the END in the output.*

The `ref_file`:

```
    testing 20 10
    jobs 15 20
    issues 0 1
    work 15 25
    Total 50 56
```

The `head_file`:

```
    testing 20 10
    jobs 15 30
    work 12 25
    games 1 2
    Total 48 67
```

Desired output:

```
TABLE,REF-IO,HEAD-IO,DIFF-IO,REF-SELECT,HEAD-SELECT,DIFF-SELECT
jobs,15,15,0,20,30,-10
work,15,12,3,25,25,0
games,0,1,-1,0,2,-2
issues,0,0,0,1,0,1
Total,50,48,2,56,67,-11
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Showing your current code would help clarify what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @John1024 I need to substract column 2 of ref_file by column 2 of head_file and show their diffrence, in addition substract column 3 of ref_file by column 3 of head_file and show their difference. All the above based on column 1 of both file and the output should not contain the rows with diff_column_2(DIFF-IO) = diff_column_3(DIFF-SELECT) = 0. Noting that the order can be random except the last row which exists in both files and should remain at the END in the output.

Comment: Are the both files have same column No.1 and number of rows?

Comment: @Costas, No the files may have some different column No. 1 values and of course have different number of rows.

Comment: And how to operate row which is not exist in `head_file` but exist in `ref_file`?

Comment: @Costas, column No. 1 values that exist in one of the files should always be displayed as shown in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        print "TABLE,REF-IO,HEAD-IO,DIFF-IO,REF-SELECT,HEAD-SELECT,DIFF-SELECT"
        OFS = ", "
    }
    FNR==NR {
        A[$1]=$2
        B[$1]=$3
        next
    }
    {
        if (!($1 in A)) {
            A[$1] = B[$1] = 0
        }
        diff_io = $2 - A[$1]
        diff_sel= $3 - B[$1]
        C[$1] = 1
    }
    diff_io || diff_sel {
        if (first) {
            print line
        }
        first = 1
        line = $1 OFS $2 OFS A[$1] OFS diff_io OFS $3 OFS B[$1] OFS diff_sel
    }
    END {
        for (name in A) {
            if (!(name in C)) {
                print name, 0, A[name], -A[name], 0, B[name], -B[name]
            }
        }
        print line
    }
    ' head_file ref_file
```

To short typing you can do the task via `join`:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e0 <(sort head_file) <(sort ref_file) -o0,1.2,2.2,0,1.3,2.3 |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        print "TABLE,REF-IO,HEAD-IO,DIFF-IO,REF-SELECT,HEAD-SELECT,DIFF-SELECT"
        OFS = ", "
    }
    {
        $4=$2-$3
        $7=$5-$6
    }
    /Total/ {
        end=$0
        next
    }
    $4!=0 || $7!=0;
    END {
        print end
    }'
```

Comment: column No. 1 values that exist in one of the files should always be displayed as shown in my example

Comment: @ekassis see updated

Comment: having wrong output.  `nawk 'FNR==NR {A[$1]=$2;B[$1]=$3; next}{if ( $1 not in A ) {A[$1] = B[$1] = 0}; diff_io = $2 - A[$1];diff_sel= $3 - B[$1];C[$1] = 1}; diff_io || diff_sel {print line; line = $1 " " $2 " " A[$1] " " diff_io " " $3 " " B[$1] " " diff_sel}END {for (name in A) {if ( name not in C ) {print name, 0, A[name], -A[name], 0, B[name], -B[name]}} print line}' head_file ref_file`  `testing 20 0 20 10 0 10  jobs 15 0 15 20 0 20  issues 0 0 1 1 work 15 0 15 25 0 25 Total 0 0 -0 0 0 -0 issues 0 -0 0 -0  jobs 0 0 -0 0 0 -0 testing 0 0 -0 0 0 -0 work 0 0 -0 0 0 -0 Total 50 0 50 26 0 26`

Comment: @ekassis Sorry it is my mistake: there is no `not` option in **awk**-syntax

Comment: Is there a way to include the header print in the command?

Comment: @ekassis You free to include what ever you want!

Comment: unfortunately the last command is not working.

nawk: syntax error at source line 1

 context is
        BEGIN { print "TABLE,REF-IO,HEAD-IO,DIFF-IO,REF-SELECT,HEAD-SELECT,DIFF-SELECT"; OFS = ", "; FNR==NR >>>  { <<<

nawk: illegal statement at source line 1

        missing }

Comment: @ekassis Parenthesis have been missed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31259/discussion-between-ekassis-and-costas).